# Multi-gpu kernel launch

Tags: cuda, multi-gpu

I am wondering if there are any advantages/drawbacks of launching a kernel on multiple GPUs via `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernelMultiDevice` when no actual cooperation is happening vs traditional loop:

```
for loop over device ids
{
    cudaSetDevice(id);
    kernel<<<..., stream[i]>>>( ... );
}
```

`cudaLaunchCooperativeKernelMultiDevice` is definitely less code than a loop...

Comment: I think you'll find that the `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernelMultiDevice` ends up being more lines of source code than the loop you have shown here.  Also, before you do a multi-device kernel launch, good practice is that you check all devices for support of that capability.  It's a function both of the device as well as the OS you are running.  You're also communicating via your source code when you do this that there is a need for it.  If there isn't actually a need for it, that's a confusing thing for people who might be maintaining your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible drawback is that the multi grid cooperative launch mechanism is not supported on all multi-GPU systems, whereas the launch-in-a-loop method is.

So by using `cudaLaunchCooperativeKernelMultiDevice` you are restricting the footprint of systems where your code can run correctly to systems which have the `cudaDevAttrCooperativeMultiDeviceLaunch` property set.

Amongst the various limitations implied by this are not being able to run on systems with GPUs in WDDM mode, and not being able to run on systems where the GPUs are not all identical in terms of compute capability.  You can read some of the other restrictions in [the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#multi-device-synchronization-cg).